# File.delete not working for 'directorya\directoryb'

Tags: c#, delete-file, temp

I want to create some function which export report to excel file,
but when I try to delete temp data it's not working.

```
File.Delete(tempFileName);
```

I try to messagebox 'tempFileName' it's correct

```
D:\test\bin\Debug\temptemp1.xls
```

then I try to test manually delete it

```
File.Delete("D:\test\bin\Debug\temptemp1.xls");
```

it's give error result '**unrecognized escape sequence**';
I try to change it like this

```
 File.Delete("D:/test/bin/Debug/temptemp1.xls");
```

and it's work smoothly

I see documentation File.Delete [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.delete%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
and it's using '\' not '/'; 
can anyone explain this to me?
(I use vs 2010 and .net 4 winform)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a regular string constant, the `\` character is an escape character so, if you want to include a literal backslash, you need to escape it (with itself):

```
File.Delete("D:\\test\\bin\\Debug\\temptemp1.xls");
```

Otherwise `\t` will become a tab, `\b` a backspace and `\D` give you your `unrecognised escape sequence` error.

Alternatively, you use a raw string to avoid all the complexities that come from escaping:

```
File.Delete(@"D:\test\bin\Debug\temptemp1.xls");
```

which doesn't do the escaping.

The reason that it works with the forward slash `/` is because Windows has, for a *long* time, been able to handle both styles (in the API, though not in the command interpreter `cmd.exe`).

Answer (score 1):

Try..

```
File.Delete(@"D:\test\bin\Debug\temptemp1.xls");
```

OR...

```
File.Delete("D:\\test\\bin\Debug\\temptemp1.xls");
```

Backslash is a special character. As documented here...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090(v=vs.71).aspx

> A character that follows a backslash character () in a
>   regular-string-literal-character must be one of the following
>   characters: ', ", \, 0, a, b, f, n, r, t, u, U, x, v. Otherwise, a
>   compile-time error occurs.